# How to retrieve footer from file in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have files which can or can NOT contain a single line as a footer.
I would like to retrieve it if exists, because it contains meta information about the file.
Is there any building function from pandas to retrieve that line?, then I can store it in a variable.
I expected something like this:

`df = pd.read_csv("path", skipfooter=1, engine"python")`

But instead of skipping the line, it is storing it in a variable.

This is how the columns kind of looks like.

- col1,col2,col3
- 100,"up",1.24
- 874,"down",3.54
- 122,"up",3.34
- Date:20200225,Start:1200,End:1300,Session:2,Exp:12,Type:"mono"

This is what I am currently using

`def getFooter():
    with open (path, "r") as f:
          footer = f.readlines()[-1]
          return footer`

Comment: Has that footer line a well known format and/or a maximum size? It could allow smarter ways to find it...

Comment: You might need `regex` to check if it has a footer or not. please give us more information

Comment: It has a dictionary format, but the number of keys in the dictionary varies mong files. However there are some keys that all files share

Comment: Have you tried df=pd.read_csv("path").iloc[-1]?

Comment: Yes, that is actually what I am currently using. I was just wondering if there is an easier way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're going to need to know what the pattern of the footer is, then read in the last line of the file and check if that pattern is in the last line.  If so your last line is your footer variable and you can read with skip footer, else just read the entire thing in and ignore last_line.

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        pass
    last_line = line

if "some value" in last_line:
    df = pd.read_csv("path", skipfooter=1, engine"python")
else:
    df = pd.read_csv("path", engine"python")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the expected footer has more columns than other rows, `on_bad_lines` (introduced in version 1.3.0.) can be used to separate the data and the footer. As documented, `on_bad_lines` specifies what to do upon encountering a bad line (a line with too many fields).

Using the callable feature (introduced in version 1.4.0. and only supported when `engine="python"`):

```
import pandas as pd

footer = [] # variable to store footer(s) data

def record_footer(bad_line):
    footer.append(bad_line)
    print(footer)

path = 'test.txt' # directory to data file.

df = pd.read_csv(path, on_bad_lines=record_footer, engine='python')

print(df)
```

The output is as follows. The first line is the extracted footer.

```
[['Date:20200225', 'Start:1200', 'End:1300', 'Session:2', 'Exp:12', 'Type:"mono"']]
   col1  col2  col3
0   100    up  1.24
1   874  down  3.54
2   122    up  3.34
```